# Не могу изменить настройки php в scotchbox

Tags: php, vagrant

Использую vagrant контейнер scotchbox. все хорошо запустилось и работает. но я хочу сменить настройки php. вывел phpinfo(). Там написало

```
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

Подключился по ssh. Отредактировал файл, перегрузил apache. Проверяю - настройки прежние.

В чем может быть проблема? Уже не знаю, что делать

Answer (score 0):

Извините, уже решил. Вся проблема была в том, что надо было переключится на учетную запись рута. Хотя до этого делал все через sudo и не работало. Но когда сделал sudo su - заработало. Всем спасибо